# Plotting multiple graphs with matplotlib subplots does not show edge colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, igraph

I am using `igraph` to analyze a network and find a specific kind of triad as subgraphs of the main network. I successfully did that but now I'm trying to plot these subgraphs in a multipanel figure using `matplotlib`.

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

# some long hidden code here to generate the main network (g)

# the triad pattern
ffl = g.Isoclass(n=3, cls=7, directed=True)

# finding the subgraphs
sub = g.get_subisomorphisms_vf2(ffl)

# trying to plot the subgraphs
ffls = []
for i in range(len(sub)):
    vtx = g.vs.select(sub[i])
    ffl = g.subgraph(vtx)
    ffl.vs['name'] = g.vs[sub[i]]['name']
    ffls.append(ffl)

visual_style = {'layout': 'reingold_tilford',
                'vertex_label_size': 15}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=7, ncols=4, figsize=(15,25))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5, hspace=0.5)
axs = axs.ravel()
for ax in axs:
    ax.set_axis_off()
for ffl, ax in zip(ffls, axs):
    ig.plot(ffl, target=ax, vertex_label=ffl.vs['name'], **visual_style)
plt.show()
```

The resulting figure shows all the subgraphs as intended but without the colors of the edges (that I already defined in the main network). I know the colors are being captured in the subgraphs because when I plot them individually the colors are there (also the attributes are correctly assigned to the edges). Only when I try to plot them all together that I have this "problem".

What I am doing wrong? It is possible to show the edge colors when using `plt.subplots()`? Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add how `g` is being created. It looks like some code is missing.

Comment: Thanks, @lepsch. It is a long code, I did not include it on purpose. But `g` is not the problem.

Comment: I see. However, I'd like to test it on my machine to find a solution. Would you prototype the simplest `g` that shows up with the same problem?

Comment: @lepsch Oh, I see. Let me do the same with some publicly available data because this network I'm working on now is private research material.

Comment: @lepsch I'm sharing with you an example through my github [link](https://github.com/annasoli/stackoverflow). Thank you for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried setting `edge_color`, `color`, `face_color` in the `plot` function but none of them worked. Actually only `edge_color` works but it sets the color for all edges.

The only way that worked was setting the `edgecolor` in the axes' children directly after plot. Take a look at the solution below:

```py
for ffl, ax in zip(ffls, axs):
    ig.plot(ffl, target=ax, vertex_label=ffl.vs['name'], **visual_style)
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1.25)
    ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.25)
    children = ax.get_children()
    for i, e in enumerate(ffl.es):
        edge = children[i + 4] # Skip the vertex and the 3 labels
        edge.set_edgecolor(e['color'])
        edge.set_in_layout(True)
```

This is the resulting screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can see available styling options [here](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html#__plot__) (there is no `face_color` or special support for planar graphs). The matplotlib backend is experimental and not feature complete in version 0.9. Version 0.10 has much improved support for matplotlib. You can try the development version to use it.